# net.peerCount is zero: Two miners are not connected

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, mining, testnets, connections

I'm trying to build a local private blockchain of Ethereum in my own PC using `Geth v1.9.15-stable-0f77f34b`. I have installed Geth in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04 OS using VMware Workstation Pro. I want to create two miners inside the virtual machine. Each runs in different terminal, I have follow this steps:

1)create two nodes:

```
geth --datadir node1 account new
geth --datadir node2 account new
```

2)genesis.json

```
{
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "config": {},
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333", "alloc": { }
}
```

3)initialize genesis:

```
geth --datadir node1 init ./genesis.json
geth --datadir node2 init ./genesis.json
```

4)To enable nodes I use:

```
geth --identity "name_of_your_node" --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir mode1 --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin" --networkid 1900 --nat "any"

geth --identity "name_of_your_node" --rpc --rpcport "8001" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir mode2 --port "30301" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin" --networkid 1900 --nat "any"
```

5)Interconnect nodes:

```
geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8001
geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

6)Make Node1 as an admin node, I use this code to find info:

```
admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://b378a4f7d9454811a89954cb97bb19589564a8e1ef24ebda07c25c2ae2a8acf35c4c14b2fd84d2a0cf92b1586eff0ea592de5f8effb0e08b1616917edf3306f1@100.69.54.149:30303?discport=0",
  enr: "enr:-JO4QI-9oLlq2ZVbjMfEry_Kk7VJ65divD9HL7jFC3tl2WwkbTc6Bc4sIqaD9MTKAEQuDfWqSw_bwoy2nqy5MAfYgssHg2V0aMrJhPxk7ASDEYwwgmlkgnY0gmlwhGRFNpWJc2VjcDI1NmsxoQOzeKT32UVIEaiZVMuXuxlYlWSo4e8k69oHwlwq4qis84N0Y3CCdl8",
  id: "fb25937ad7ced1cf77a820fc34f93d42135cf2760508db94dd56c2ca05bb92b5",
  ip: "100.69.54.149",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30303",
  name: "Geth/name_of_your_node/v1.9.15-stable-0f77f34b/linux-amd64/go1.14.2",
  ports: {
    discovery: 0,
    listener: 30303
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      config: {
        byzantiumBlock: 4370000,
        chainId: 1,
        constantinopleBlock: 7280000,
        daoForkBlock: 1920000,
        daoForkSupport: true,
        eip150Block: 2463000,
        eip150Hash: "0x2086799aeebeae135c246c65021c82b4e15a2c451340993aacfd2751886514f0",
        eip155Block: 2675000,
        eip158Block: 2675000,
        ethash: {},
        homesteadBlock: 1150000,
        istanbulBlock: 9069000,
        muirGlacierBlock: 9200000,
        petersburgBlock: 7280000
      },
      difficulty: 17179869184,
      genesis: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      head: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      network: 1900
    }
  }
}
```

7)another node I use this code to connect to node 1:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://b378a4f7d9454811a89954cb97bb19589564a8e1ef24ebda07c25c2ae2a8acf35c4c14b2fd84d2a0cf92b1586eff0ea592de5f8effb0e08b1616917edf3306f1@100.69.54.149:30303?discport=0")
true
```

8)but the nodes are not connected:

```
> net.peerCount
0
> net.listening
true
```

Have I missed something? please help?
I have another question: why the IP in `admin.nodeInfo` is `"100.69.54.149"`, it's not my IP how to change that?

Comment: By default geth tries to use your external ip, you can disable that by adding `--nat none` to the command line, an alternative is to tell him explicitly your address `--nat extip:<IP address>`. See other command line parameters here https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options.

Comment: Please, add the command line used as an answer so it can help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `--nat none` to `geth --identity "name_of_your_node" --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir mode1 --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin" --networkid 1900 --nat none`